# Add two webview in framelayout

Tags: android, webview, android-framelayout

I want to add two webview in a layout..I use frameLayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview1"
        android:layout_width="350dip"
        android:layout_height="350dip" />


    <WebView
        android:layout_height="250dip"
        android:layout_width="250dip"
        android:id="@+id/webview2"    
    />

    </FrameLayout>
```

And in Main Activity :

```
    web1=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview1);
    web2=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview2);

    web1.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
    web2.loadUrl("http://www.youtube.com");

    web2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Animation anim=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(FrameWebViewActivity.this, android.R.anim.slide_in_left);
            web2.setAnimation(anim);
        }
    });
```

But when run project,it only display webview youtube full screen ..I want to display both two webview..What i must do??

Answer (score 2):

Use another layout , a [`FrameLayout`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html) is used to display only a single child element.

I would suggest using a linear layout and specifying weights to divide the views into the desired proportions.

Answer (score 2):

One thing you need to remember while using Framelayout is **"When adding multiple views to a FrameLayout, each will be stacked on top of the previous one."** So better use any other parent layout like Linear layout or Relative layout & in that use two framelayouts..

Code:

```
   </RelativeLayout>

      <?xml version=”1.0” encoding=”utf-8”?>
        <RelativeLayout
           android:id=”@+id/RLayout”
           android:layout_width=”fill_parent”
           android:layout_height=”fill_parent”
           xmlns:android=”http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android”>

         <FrameLayout>
            <WebView
              android:id="@+id/webview1"
              android:layout_width="350dip"
              android:layout_height="350dip" />
         </FrameLayout> 

         <FrameLayout>
            <WebView
               android:layout_height="250dip"
               android:layout_width="250dip"
               android:id="@+id/webview2" />
        </FrameLayout> 
      </RelativeLayout>
```